# Restrict direct access to image url in laravel

Tags: laravel

If i give image path directly it accessible now. I want image accessible only for if user loged in.
Ex: 
This is image path  http://localhost:8000/images/test.jpg
If user give this path without loged in through error message as access dined

Can you help me..

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: In that case store the image in `resources/assets/` folder and create a route and method to access the image and put that method under `auth` middleware

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to fix this problem, the way I would use is to save all images in your `resources/assets/` folder outside of the public folder.

Now you could create a route like this:

```
Route::get('images/{file}', 'ImageController@getImage')->where('file', '.*');
```

And now in your `ImageController`, you can check if the user is logged in. If so, you can load the image from the resources folder and send it in a file response. If they are not logged in, there is no way they will be able to access the file.

Comment: In my case images are stored in public folder.

Comment: I tried this one . But not working.......                  Route::get('/images/test.jpg', function () {
    if(!auth()->user()) {
        return 'unauthorized';
    }
        return'authorized';
});

Comment: I tried with your answer. Its working only for image name is wrong. If i give correct image name its not working. Image is accessible without loged in

Comment: Hello, I have simmilar problem.

I created a ImageController
   
    php artisan make:controller ImageController

I've added a method in controller:

    public function getImage($image){
        $file = Storage::get($image);
        return $file;
    }

I've modified a little your routes:

    Route::get('images/{file}', [ ImageController::class, 'getImage' ])->where('file', '.*');

Answer (score -1):

**Tested with Laravel 8**

Define a new disk in file: config/filesystem.php

```
'disks' => [
    // ...
    'private' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/private'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'private',
    ],
],
```

Define web route in file: routes/web.php

```
Route::any('/private{any}', function (Request $request, $file) {
    abort_if(!Storage::disk('private')->exists($file), 404, "File doesn't exist.");
    return Storage::disk('private')->response($file);
})->middleware('auth')->where('any', '.*');
```

Upload image file to folder: storage/private

Test on your localhost at: http://localhost:8000/private/image_name.jpg